# AS3 Flash Flip image

Tags: actionscript-3

I could really need some help here. I'm trying to create a simple image-fliping-app that looks something like this: http://www.skistar.com/sv/Are/Skidskola/Skistar-Experience/om/

My app, just like this one, loads it's images dynamically (using XML). My app will only contain 4 fliping objects (i.e. 8 images).

Has anybody some guidance or code for that matter that I can study to get this working? 
That would be really sweet! :-)

// Nicke

Comment: Your question looks too generic. Is there any specific step you have problem with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can fake the flipping with a simple scaleX scaling. Basically you've got the two images on top of each other and when the mouse is over them you scale down the visible one and when it's scaleX value equals 0, you start scaling up the other image. The reference point of the images should be centered.

I will try to give you an example but a bit busy at the moment.

Hope it helps,
Rob

Answer (score 1):

[`img.scaleX = -1;`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#scaleX)

[`img.scaleY = -1;`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#scaleY)

Comment: Not sure why someone voted down your comment. We do this in flash game programming all the time. Very quick for the flash player.